# How do I make a list of multiple inputs by the user by using JOptionPane and arrays?

Tags: java, swing

I have to correct all of my IT-Class homeworks and I struggle with one of them.
To give you a short breakdown; I basically have to use `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` in order to get the Users input of their 4 favourite music artists. Furthermore I have to save those inputs in an array called `singers[]`; I have to utilize a for loop asking the names of the 4 artists using `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`, then save that input in the mentioned array, and output the 4 artists, however if one of the artist name is  "heino", the program has to close immediately by `System.exit(0)`.

I got most of that down, however I struggle at getting input and output for the 4 artist names.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] singer = new String[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < singer.length; i++) {
            singer[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How is your favourite artist called? :");
            if(singer[i].equals("Heino")){
                System.exit(0);
            }

            else{
                singer[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you have any other favourite artists? : ");
            }

        for (String bestesinger : singer){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The name of your favourite artists are: " + singer[0] + singer[1] + singer[2] + singer[3]);
        }   
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of "Do you have any other favourite artists?" ? The input should be yes or no to this question or a singer's name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed your program like shown below. And now it works. Key points are:

You had nested `for` loops, but you should use 2 separate `for` loops.

You don't need the `else` block in the first `for` loop.

Second `showMessageDialog()` call is moved outside the second `for` loop. In the second `for` loop, singer names are collected to `output` variable.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Singers {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] singer = new String[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < singer.length; i++) {
      singer[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How is your favourite artist called? :");
      if (singer[i].equals("Heino")) {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    }

    String output = "";
    for (String bestesinger : singer){
      output = output + bestesinger + " ";
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The name of your favourite artists are: " + output);
  }
}
```